# TypeError: Instance of '_JsonMap': type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of type

Tags: json, parsing, dart, types

I am trying to parse JSON file inside Dart application. I think I am using the correct code yet Dart type system is complaining

`TypeError: Instance of '_JsonMap': type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<double>>'`

I have looked at solutions for this and tried doing it like this article states, however I can't seem to do it right.

You can run the code in [Dartpad here](https://dartpad.dev/2337794faa4d1bebf9e6c6ecf72b9164?null_safety=true) or see the code below:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

const STRINGIFIED_RESPONSE = '''
  {
    "status": "ok",
    "body": {
      "routes": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              [ 1.1, 1.2 ],
              [ 3.3, 4.4 ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
''';

void main() {
  try {
    final response = jsonDecode(STRINGIFIED_RESPONSE);
    final firstRoute = response['body'] != null && response['body']['routes'] != null
      ? response['body']['routes'][0]
      : null;
    
    if (firstRoute == null) {
      print('Nothing to parse.');
      return;
    }
    final route = Route.fromJSON(firstRoute);
    print(route.geometry.list);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

class Position {
  Position({this.lon = 0.0, this.lng = 0.0});
  double lon;
  double lng;
}

class CoordinateList {
  CoordinateList({required this.list});
  CoordinateList.fromJSON(List<List<double>> data) :
    list = data.map((coordinate) => Position(lon: coordinate[1], lng: coordinate[0])).toList();
  List<Position> list = [];
}

class Route {
  Route({required this.geometry});
  Route.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> data) :
    geometry = CoordinateList.fromJSON(data['geometry'] as List<List<double>>);
  CoordinateList geometry;
}
```

I think the problem comes from the line: `CoordinateList.fromJSON(data['geometry'] as List<List<double>>)`. I'm not sure how I should cast dynamic type of `geometry` property so the type system thinks it's 2-dimensional list containing float numbers.

I'm fairly new to Dart so maybe there's more idiomatic approach to this but I have been stuck on this for few hours and would like to move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing `CoordinateList` and `Route` classes since I only needed to access property from JSON anyway.

The way I "forced" Dart to understand my intention was to actually use `as List<dynamic>` casting when retrieving `coordinates` property and then calling `map` where I cast to `List<dynamic>` again. This `map` call is basically just to please the compiler but hey, it works:

```dart
final coordinates = (geometry['coordinates'] as List<dynamic>)
      .map((innerList) => innerList as List<dynamic>).toList();
```

This way `coordinates` variable becomes `List<List<dynamic>>` which is OK and works.

[Link to Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/a91f6d46d0bf28b84258313d9844ba01?null_safety=true)

This is updated code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

const STRINGIFIED_RESPONSE = '''
  {
    "status": "ok",
    "body": {
      "routes": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              [ 1.1, 1.2 ],
              [ 3.3, 4.4 ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
''';

void main() {
  try {
    final response = jsonDecode(STRINGIFIED_RESPONSE);
    final firstRoute = response['body'] != null && response['body']['routes'] != null
      ? response['body']['routes'][0]
      : null;
    
    if (firstRoute == null) {
      print('Nothing to parse.');
      return;
    }
    final geometry = firstRoute['geometry'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final coordinates = (geometry['coordinates'] as List<dynamic>)
      .map((innerList) => innerList as List<dynamic>).toList();
    final positions = coordinates.map((coords) => Position(lon: coords[0], lng: coords[1])).toList();
    print(positions);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

class Position {
  Position({required this.lon, required this.lng});
  Position.fromJSON(List<double> data)
    : lon = data[1],
      lng = data[0];
  final double lon;
  final double lng;
  
  List<double> getLatLng() {
    return [ lon, lng ];
  }
}
```